# ggVis : creating a plot with multiple layers on different dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggvis

I'm trying to reproduce a ggplot2 plot using ggvis.
The plot aims at representing the coordinates of points (from a Correspondence Analysis) together with their clusters (hclust) Standard Dispersion Ellipses.

---

## TL; DR

I'd like to make a ggvis plot with multiple layers based on multiple datasets.
Thus, the functional/pipe approach stops me from grouping one of the layers and not the other.

The whole (briefly commented) code is there : https://gist.github.com/RCura/a135446cda079f4fbc10

---

Here's the code for creating the data:

```
 a <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 50, sd = 5)

 b <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 50, sd = 5)

 c <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 50, sd = 5)

 mydf <- data.frame(A = a, B = b, C = c, row.names = c(1:100))

 library(ade4)

 myCA <- dudi.coa(df = mydf,scannf = FALSE,  nf = 2)

 myDist <- dist.dudi(myCA, amongrow = TRUE)

 myClust <- hclust(d = myDist, method = "ward.D2")

 myClusters <- cutree(tree = myClust, k = 3)

 myCAdata <- data.frame(Axis1 = myCA$li$Axis1, Axis2 = myCA$li$Axis2, Cluster = as.factor(myClusters))

 library(ellipse) # Compute Standard Deviation Ellipse

 df_ellipse <- data.frame()

 for(g in levels(myCAdata$Cluster)){
   df_ellipse <- rbind(df_ellipse,
                 cbind(as.data.frame(
                 with(myCAdata[myCAdata$Cluster==g,],
                 ellipse(cor(Axis1, Axis2),
                 level=0.7,
                 scale=c(sd(Axis1),sd(Axis2)),
                 centre=c(mean(Axis1),mean(Axis2))))),
                 Cluster=g))
 }
```

I can plot this through ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)

myPlot <- ggplot(data=myCAdata, aes(x=Axis1, y=Axis2,colour=Cluster)) +
  geom_point(size=1.5, alpha=.6) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour="black",alpha = 0.5, linetype = "longdash" ) +
  geom_hline(xintercept = 0, colour="black", alpha = 0.5, linetype = "longdash" ) +
  geom_path(data=df_ellipse, aes(x=x, y=y,colour=Cluster), size=0.5, linetype=1)
myPlot
```

[image]

But I can't find how to plot this using ggvis.

I can plot the 2 different layers:

```
library(ggvis)

all_values <- function(x) { paste0(names(x), ": ", format(x), collapse = "<br />")}

 ggDF <- myCAdata

 ggDF$name <- row.names(ggDF)

## Coordinates plot
myCoordPlot <- ggvis(x = ~Axis1, y = ~Axis2, key := ~name, data = ggDF) %>%

  layer_points(size := 15, fill= ~Cluster, data = ggDF) %>%

  add_tooltip(all_values, "hover")

 myCoordPlot
```

[image]

### Ellipses plot (no tooltip requested)

```
 myEllPlot <- ggvis(data = df_ellipse, x = ~x,  y = ~ y) %>%

  group_by(Cluster) %>%

  layer_paths(x= ~x, y= ~y, stroke = ~Cluster, strokeWidth := 1)

 myEllPlot
```

[image]

But when I want to plot the 2 layers on the same plot :

```
 myFullPlot <- ggvis(data = df_ellipse, x = ~x,  y = ~ y) %>%

 layer_paths(x= ~x, y= ~y, stroke = ~Cluster, strokeWidth := 1) %>%

 layer_points(x = ~Axis1, y= ~Axis2, size := 15, fill= ~Cluster, data = ggDF) %>%

 add_tooltip(all_values, "hover")

 myFullPlot
```

[image]

The ellipses are not grouped, so, the color don't fit, and the ellipses are not separated.
If I try to group my Ellipses, it doesn't work: the group_by is only required by the layer_paths, and it mess up the layer_points.

Any idea how to make this work?
And sorry for this very long post, but I've been trying to make this work for hours :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that when you try to combine the two, you do not group_by `Cluster` on the ellipsis dataset. You need to do the following for it to work:

```
myFullPlot <- ggvis(data = df_ellipse, x = ~x, y = ~ y) %>% group_by(Cluster) %>%

  layer_paths(stroke = ~Cluster, strokeWidth := 1) %>%

  layer_points(x = ~Axis1, y= ~Axis2, size := 15, fill= ~Cluster, data = ggDF)

myFullPlot
```

[image]

And this way you get the graph you want!

P.S. I assume there is some randomness in your data creation because I got a different data set than yours.

Comment: Thanks a lot LyzandeR, it works just as expected. I had try to put the group_by, of course, but obviously not on the right position.
For the data, it's based (on this post) on rnorm so that's it's easily reproducible, but of course, the data doesn't matter here, only the method.