# ggvis: Combine multiple datasets in single plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggvis

I have read a [similar post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659921/ggvis-creating-a-plot-with-multiple-layers-on-different-dataset), but was not able to adapt the answer to my specific case.  I am working with time series data and would like to combine two different data sets into the same plot.  Although I *could* combine the data into one dataframe, I am really interested in understanding how to reference multiple datasets.

**Mock Data:**

```
require(ggvis)

dfa <- data.frame(
date_a = seq(from= as.Date("2015-06-10"), 
        to= as.Date("2015-07-01"), by= 1),
val_a = c(2585.150, 2482.200, 3780.186, 3619.601, 
        0.000, 0.000, 3509.734, 3020.405, 
        3271.897, 3019.003, 3172.084, 0.000, 
        0.000, 3319.927, 2673.428, 3331.382, 
        3886.957, 2859.887, 0.000, 0.000, 
        2781.443, 2847.377) )

dfb <- data.frame(
date_b = seq(from= as.Date("2015-07-02"), 
        to= as.Date("2015-07-15"), by= 1),
val_b = c(3250.75429, 3505.43477, 3208.69141,
        -2.08175, -27.30244, 3324.62348, 
        2820.91075, 3250.75429, 3505.43477,
        3208.69141, -2.08175, -27.30244,
        3324.62348, 2820.91075) )
```

Using the data provided above, I am able to create separate plots with the code below:

**Separate Plots: (Works)**

```
dfa %>%
ggvis( x= ~date_a , y= ~val_a, stroke := "black", opacity := 0.5 ) %>% 
    scale_datetime("x", nice = "month", domain = c(as.Date("2015-06-10"),
    as.Date("2015-07-15") )) %>%
    layer_lines() %>% layer_points( fill := "black" )

dfb %>%
ggvis( x= ~date_b , y= ~val_b, stroke := "red", opacity := 0.5 ) %>% 
    scale_datetime("x", nice = "month", domain = c(as.Date("2015-06-10"),
    as.Date("2015-07-15") )) %>%
    layer_lines() %>% layer_points( fill := "red" )
```

The desired output is these two lines (black and red) to be on the same plot.  Here are a couple of unsuccessful attempts:

**Attempt #1 adapted from [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659921/ggvis-creating-a-plot-with-multiple-layers-on-different-dataset):**

```
ggvis( data = dfa, x = ~date_a, y = ~val_a) %>% layer_lines(stroke := "black",  opacity := 0.5 ) %>%
    layer_lines( data = dfb, x= ~date_b , y= ~val_b, stroke := "red", 
    opacity := 0.5 ) %>% 
    scale_datetime("x", nice = "month", domain = c(as.Date("2015-06-10"), 
    as.Date("2015-07-15") )) 

## Error in new_prop.default(x, property, scale, offset, mult, env, event,  : 
##  Unknown input to prop: c(16618, 16619, 16620, 16621, 16622, 16623, 16624, ...
```

**Attempt #2 based on [RStudio documentation](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/data-hierarchy.html):**

```
ggvis( data = NULL, x = ~date_a, y = ~val_a) %>%
    layer_lines(stroke := "black",  opacity := 0.5, data = dfa ) %>%
    layer_lines( x= ~date_b , y= ~val_b, stroke := "red", 
    opacity := 0.5, data = dfb ) %>% 
    scale_datetime("x", nice = "month", domain = c(as.Date("2015-06-10"), 
    as.Date("2015-07-15") )) 

## Error in func() : attempt to apply non-function
```

Here is a minimalistic implementation in ggplot2:

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = dfa, aes(x = date_a, y = val_a ), colour = "black") +     
  geom_line(data = dfb, aes(x = date_b, y = val_b ), colour = "red")
```

[image: ggplot example]

Again, a working solution and brief explanation would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it looks like `layer_lines` may not properly by taking the `data` argument.  I think you can successfully use `layer_paths` here.  They work similarly, but `layer_paths` works in the order of the data so you'd need to make sure your time series are arranged correctly before plotting.

First, when I look at the `layer_paths` basic function it, like many other layer functions, has a specific data argument.

```
layer_paths
function (vis, ..., data = NULL) 
{
    add_mark(vis, "line", props(..., env = parent.frame()), data, 
        deparse2(substitute(data)))
}
<environment: namespace:ggvis>
```

While `layer_lines` has the `...` for more arguments, it doesn't have a `data` argument and it doesn't seem like things work with it.

```
layer_lines
function (vis, ...) 
{
    x_var <- vis$cur_props$x$value
    layer_f(vis, function(x) {
        x <- auto_group(x, exclude = c("x", "y"))
        x <- dplyr::arrange_(x, x_var)
        emit_paths(x, props(...))
    })
}
<environment: namespace:ggvis>
```

To test, I made a really basic graph, trying to use the `data` argument in `layer_lines`.

```
ggvis() %>%
    layer_lines(data = dfb, x= ~date_b , y= ~val_b, stroke := "red")
```

This fails with an error.

> Error in func() : attempt to apply non-function

Here's the same code using `layer_paths` instead:

```
ggvis() %>%
    layer_paths(data = dfb, x= ~date_b , y= ~val_b, stroke := "red")
```

[image]

So, that works, which means as long as you order your dataset by your dates your graphic should work fine by just replacing `layer_lines` with `layer_paths`.

```
ggvis(data = dfa, x = ~date_a, y = ~val_a) %>% 
    layer_paths(stroke := "black",  opacity := 0.5 ) %>%
    layer_paths(data = dfb, x = ~date_b , y= ~val_b, stroke := "red", 
                opacity := 0.5 ) %>% 
    scale_datetime("x", nice = "month", domain = c(as.Date("2015-06-10"), as.Date("2015-07-15") ))
```

[image]

This seemed odd to me, and I have missed something.  I didn't see anything in the open or closed issues on the `ggvis` [github page](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues) and you might consider filing one.

Comment: I think you should file an issue. I came to the same conclusions like you, and it seems like an unexpected behaviour to me.

Comment: Thank you for the working solution and explanation.  It worked for me as I have my time-series sorted.  I have also posted the issue on github.